# Can't print to PDF in Slim Framework, Twig, and DomPDF

Tags: pdf, twig, slim, dompdf

I have been struggling with this and I can't get it to work, despite that in some other posts they say you can use the Twig's `render()` function, I get the folowing error:

> Requested HTML document contains no data. Dompdf\Exception

My code so far is:

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$app->post('/my/path/for/printing',function()use($app){
    //echo '<p>printing to pdf ... ☺</p>';
    $request=$app->request;
    /* code for retrieving data from the database ... done.*/

    $variables = [
        'param1' =>  $param1,
        'param2' =>  $param2,
    ];

    $dompdf = new Dompdf();


    $content = $app->render('path/for/the/view.print.twig', $variables);
    $dompdf->loadHtml($content);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream('sample.pdf');

})->name('my.path.for.printing');
```

If I render my view, the data is displayed correctly. But with dompdf is not working.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Otherwise, can you explain with an example of any other package how to print a Twig view in PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render()` doesn't return the HTML. Try:

```php
$content = $app-view->fetch('path/for/the/view.print.twig', $variables);
```

Comment: This part now it's working. However, I can't make it work yet. I have now further problems, such as `permission denied on unlink() function`. I am trying other packages and still I have errors here and there. I can't make it work! :( I have tried fpdf and it only prints out bad characters on screen. :( I can't make work these PDF packages on Slim Framework 2.x :( Any ideas?

Comment: I am struggling with that on windows 7 ... any hints how to fix it? Permissions problem are reported on `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: dompdf uses a temporary directory to store remote resources (e.g. images). By default it uses the value returned by `sys_get_temp_dir()`. If you don't have read/write access to that location you can try modifying where these files are stored using `$dompdf->set_option('tmpDir', '...');` (fill in your temporary directory).

Comment: @BrianS Thanks, i could change the dir. But still, I can't solve this unlink() permission denied issue. This is driving me mad. I can't find Apache2.4 from the services list to check the permissions. I go to this folder, checked all permissions and nothing. This is not working.

Comment: Okkei. I solved it by commenting all the `unlink()` functions inside the `FontMetrics.php` file and it is finally working.

Comment: doesn't really solve the issue, but as a work-around it's ok. you'll have to remember to do that if you upgrade in the future.